# A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed | nw.js error connecting canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, node-webkit

I use nw.js and when trying to connect the canvas module (node-canvas), this error appears. Installing a different version of node/canvas didn't help. The error appears when
 `require('canvas')`
Error image:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv1dA.png)

````
Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\N:\BOTSer\Protocol\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1224:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:97:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (N:\BOTSer\Protocol\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1179:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That module requires a native build that is compatible with your global install of Node.js. If the version of Node in NW.js doesn't match your global install, then the built binary will not work with it. Things always work better when you switch your global Node.js install version to match what is built into NW.js. You can use `nvm-windows` or `nvm` to control your global Node version, just be sure to uninstall Node.js first before using a Node Version Manager so you don't have two conflicting global installs. You can check the Node.js version in NW.js by running `console.log(process.version);`.

- https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm (OSX/Linux)
- https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows (Windows 8+)
- https://github.com/nullivex/nodist (Windows 7)
- https://nwjs.io/versions.json (All NW.js versions data)

If my assumption is correct then:

1. Open your app, right-click > inspect > console > process.version > write down the Node version you need > close your app.
2. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
3. Uninstall Node.js globally
4. Install the correct Node Version Manager for your OS
5. Use the Node Version Manager to install the version your wrote down in step 1
6. Do a fresh `npm install` in your project and try running it again

Though I'm very confused as to why you would be using the native `canvas` module with NW.js. Why are you packaging an entire browser with your application that has a canvas built in, and then pulling in a second tool and using it instead? Just use the browser's canvas.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: Indeed, at node.js was version 17.4.0 while nw.js had 17.3.0. Reinstalled the node version.js (with reboot) and reinstalled all modules, but alas - the error did not disappear.
Why I use my own canvas module - I lack functions such as LoadImage and toBuffer.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue (NW.js 0.60.0, Node.js 17.3.0). Sometimes native builds for Node are built using Node-GYP and aren't compatible with NW.js, instead they need rebuilt using NW-GYP. More details here: https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/guide-to-nw-js-versions-5d38#0392-20190627